# My PHP array issue

Tags: php, arrays

This will be a pretty strange question, but bear with me.

I'm coding a browser based game, and each player has an amount of guards, each with 100 health. Every time they are shot, the guards lose health. If all the guards are dead, the player takes the health instead.

The shot damage always overlaps as well, so if player has 3 guards, and the top guard has 60 health, a shot of 100 will kill guard 3 and leave guard 2 with 60 health.

i use a php array to sort this, and it works, except when it comes down to the players health. It doesn't calculate correctly, eg all a players guards are dead and the player has 60 health left. He is shot for 100, but instead of dying the health loops round so he has some other number health instead of -40.

```
$p_bg = array(); // players guard count
$p_bg[0] = $rs[bgs_hp2]; // only the top guard hp is saved (bgs_hp2)
$p_hp = $rs[hp2]; // players health
$dmg = 80 // shot damage

$x = 0;
while($x < $rs[BGs2]) { $p_bg[$x] = 100; $x++; } 

// As long as there's still damage to take and bgs to take it:
while($dmg && !empty($p_bg)) {
   $soak = min($p_bg[0], $dmg); // not more than the first bg can take
   $p_bg[0] -= $soak; // remove hps from the first bg
   $dmg -= $soak; // deduct from the amount of damage to tage

   if ($p_bg[0] == 0) {
      // bodyguard dead, remove him from the array
      array_shift($p_bg);
      }
   }

// If there's any damage left over, it goes to hp
$p_hp = $p_hp - $dmg;
```

Comment: I'm not on a PHP box at the moment, so can't do it for you, but this is the kind of bug `xdebug` was made for. Install it to walk through your code and it will show you where the variable is being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the contents of `$rs` or knowing what the constants `bgs_hp2`, `hp2`, and `BGs2` are, it's hard to say, but it seems like the problem lies around this combination of lines:

```
$p_bg = array(); // Create an empty array
$p_bg[0] = $rs[bgs_hp2]; // Populate the first index, possibly null?
$x = 0;
while($x < $rs[BGs2]) { $p_bg[$x] = 100; $x++; }
```

I'd suspect `BGs2` is the bodyguard count for the player? It seems that you're setting the top bodyguard's health to 100 each time this code is hit. Maybe it would be more clear if it was rearranged as follows:

```
$p_bg = array($rs[bgs_hp2]);
for ($x = 0; $x < $rs[BGs2]; $x++) { $p_bg[] = 100; }
```

Other than that, log out your variables (using `print_r($var)` or `var_dump($var)` as necessary) to see the actual data you're executing on. Good luck!

Comment: i think that may be it that, I wasn't setting the current bodyguards health. Thanks

Comment: `BGs2` should be between quotes.